# Rails: Handling different versions of gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I have a rails 5.2 application with `rvm` installed:

```
=> ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.4.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I want to add the ability to take an automated backup of the database, so installed the `backup` gem.  I understand that this shouldn't be added to the `GemFile` due to some of its dependencies being relatively old, so I used the command `gem install backup-v5.0.0.beta2`

When I run `gem list` there are a number of gems which have two version numbers, e.g. `open4 (1.3.4, 1.3.0)`

I am running into problems when I try to manually trigger the backup routine via `backup perform -t db_backup --config-file /Users/<path_to_my_rails_project>/config/Backup/config.rb`, which produces the error:

```
[error] CLI::Error
[error] --- Wrapped Exception ---
[error] Gem::LoadError: You have already activated open4 1.3.0, but your Gemfile requires open4 1.3.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

Following the steer in the error message, `bundle exec backup perform -t db_backup --config-file /Users/<path_to_my_rails_project>/config/Backup/config.rb` produces the error:

```
/Users/<my_username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:462:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable backup for gem backup. backup is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
```

**Please could you advise how I should be installing the `backup` gem and running the task without hitting errors due to different versions of the same gem being installed**

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you haven't version locked the gem like so: `gem open4, '~> 1.3.4'`

Try `bundle update open4 backup`. I would try the latest version of the gem as well.

Another option is to ditch this gem and try https://github.com/javan/whenever and just run a simple `pg_dump`, or not use any gems and add a cron job that creates a pg_dump with the timestamp in the filename.

These issues can be hard to debug, but my approach is to generally start removing gems and letting bundler figure out its dependency tree on its own. The more you define in your Gemfile them more chances bundler will have a version mismatch thus throwing an error like the one you're seeing.